# Is it possible to format a table filled with pictures in latex like in this picture?

Tags: tables, floats, formatting

[image: Picture I want to reproduce. Specifically, I would like the cells with the pictures colored, and the pictures centered in the cells. The $\tau_{coal}$ underneath the moment of contact would also be nice. In the PDF it is listed as a figure, if that helps.]

Picture I want to reproduce. Specifically, I would like the cells with the pictures colored, and the pictures centered in the cells. The `$\tau_{coal}$` underneath the moment of contact would also be nice. In the PDF it is listed as a figure, if that helps. I am trying it out in excel, but the placement of the pictures is a little awkward, and I don't have too much experience in there. If there is an alternative (non-latex) way of doing this, that's also fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are several ways to do this and there should actually already exist ideas for solutions on this site and elsewhere on the internet. Please show what you tried so far and tell where exactly you got stuck as this will help others help you best with your concrete problem.

Comment: I guess my question is more accurate to ask as 'Is latex the best way to do this?', as it has a lot of figures and gets annoying to code in Latex. I've know continued trying it in excel, but it doesn't look anywhere nearly as good. Would a way to do this in Latex be to first Create a table with includegraphics within the cells for each picture and second use a package for coloring the cells? If so, do you know how to get text underneath the picture? or can you use a caption for that?

Comment: A graphic is just a box in LaTeX and just typeset as if they were a (large) letter. So, yes, you can just place the graphics using `\includegraphics`. If you want to add a caption, I would suggest you use a `p` column and simply add a `\newline` for a line break. You might also want to take a look at the `tabularray` package that simplifies typesetting of tables in LaTeX and also provides extensive support for colored tables.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and compare the result with what I got from Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, something like the following could serve as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray, siunitx, graphicx}

\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}

\newcommand{\vcenterimg}[1]{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\height+1ex\relax}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{ 
    colspec = { *{6}{c} },
    cells = { font=\footnotesize },
    cell{2}{2-Z} = { font=\tiny },
    cell{1-2}{1} = { l, font=\bfseries },
    vlines,
    hlines,
    hline{2,3} = {2}{-}{},
} 
Time (ms) 
    & $\gamma$ = \qty{10}{\milli\newton\per\meter}
    & \qty{20}{\milli\newton\per\meter}
    & \qty{30}{\milli\newton\per\meter}
    & \qty{40}{\milli\newton\per\meter}
    & \qty{50}{\milli\newton\per\meter} \\
Moment of contact 
    & { \vcenterimg{example-image} \\[2pt] $\tau_\textrm{coal}$ = \qty{4.24}{\milli\second} }
    & { \vcenterimg{example-image} \\[2pt] $\tau_\textrm{coal}$ = \qty{4.04}{\milli\second} }
    & { \vcenterimg{example-image} \\[2pt] $\tau_\textrm{coal}$ = \qty{3.92}{\milli\second} }
    & { \vcenterimg{example-image} \\[2pt] $\tau_\textrm{coal}$ = \qty{3.85}{\milli\second} }
    & { \vcenterimg{example-image} \\[2pt] $\tau_\textrm{coal}$ = \qty{3.81}{\milli\second} } \\
3.0 
    & \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \SetCell{cyan} \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \SetCell{cyan} \vcenterimg{example-image} \\
3.25
    & \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \SetCell{cyan} \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \SetCell{cyan} \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \vcenterimg{example-image}
    & \vcenterimg{example-image} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's really detailed. I'm sure this will work